# Provide default variable value from UI to parameters in yaml pipeline

Tags: azure, azure-devops, parameters, azure-pipelines-yaml

I have used parameters and it works fine. This works fine when we run the pipeline manually by selecting the options(prod dev and qa) and if we schedule the pipeline the pipeline will pick the default value from parameter. But what if someone want to update the default variable not in the yaml but in the variables from the UI button(variable button top right side of screen). In this case how to manage the condition when someone update the variable value in UI(variable button top right side of screen), Means they want to update the default variable  value from the UI(variable button top right side of screen) variable, not from the yaml.
Here UI means "variable button top right side of screen"

below is the sample code

```
variables:

  ${{ if eq( parameters.Environment, 'prod' ) }}: 
    buildVersion: 'prod'
  ${{ elseif eq( parameters.Environment, 'dev' ) }}:   
    buildVersion: 'dev'
  ${{ else }}: 
    buildVersion: 'test'

parameters:
    - name: Environment
      type: string
      default: $(env)
      values:
        - qa
        - dev
        - prod
```

I have define a variable in UI with name env and values would be prod, dev and qa same as above parameters.

Comment: difference between parameters and variables is that parameters are visible on UI, variables are NOT meant for UI.

Comment: Thanks for responding. UI means "variable button top right side of screen" which you can see after clicking edit pipeline.